# What Java Equivalent method to Apache's Hex.encodeHexString() Method

Tags: java, java-8

I use Java8 and I wonder if Java8 has an equivalent method to org.apache.commons.codec.Hex.encodeHexString

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`Integer.toHexString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-) is available. As is [`BigInteger.toString(int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString-int-). Both can encode to hex.

Comment: Hex.encodeHexString() - input is a byte[] and output is String.

Comment: Just telling you what is available built-in.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you really need without seeing example of input and expected output, but based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261103/what-java-equivalent-method-to-apaches-hex-encodehexstring-method/35261383#comment58234715_35261187) under [@Elliott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35261187/1393766):

> Hex.encodeHexString() - input is a byte[] and output is String.

you may be looking for [`HexBinaryAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/HexBinaryAdapter.html) class and its

- `String marshal(byte[] bytes)`
- `byte[] unmarshal(String s)`

methods (although they are ***non-static*** so you will need instance of this adapter).

---

They internally invoke these **static** methods:

- `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes)`
- `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s)`

So you may want to take a look at [DatatypeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) class.

Comment: I will try it and let you know :-)    Thanks!